# Mvc core edit action not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So, I have this User Entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Transport.Data.Entities;

namespace Transport.Data.Entities
{
    public class User : BaseEntity
    {
        public String FirstName { get; set; }
        public String LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDay { get; set; }
        public String Email { get; set; }
        public String UserName { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public List<Viaje> Viaje { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

and here is the ViewModel for the Entity

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Text;
using Transport.Data.Entities;
using Transport.Model.Infraestructure;

namespace Transport.Model.ViewModel
{
    public class ViajeViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Route { get; set; }
        public string Destination { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public DateTime DepartureTime { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public Viaje Viaje { get; set; }
        public List<User> User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Update Repository

```
DataResult IRepository<T>.Update(T entity)
{
    DataResult result = new DataResult();

    try
    { 
        result.Data = entity;
        context.SaveChanges();
        result.Successfull = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.LogError(ex);
        result.Successfull = false;
    }

    return result;
}
```

And my update service

```
public ServiceResult Update(Vm viewModel)
{
    ServiceResult serviceResult = new ServiceResult();

    var ToUpdate = this.Repository.GetById((int)viewModel.Id).Data;

    if (ToUpdate == null)
    {
        serviceResult.Success = false;
        serviceResult.ResultTitle = "ERROR: Record No Found";
        //serviceResult.Messages.Add(Error.GetErrorMessage(Error.RecordNotFound));

        return serviceResult;
    }

    var Entity = MapperHelper.Instance.Map<Vm, Ent>(viewModel);

    var result = this.Repository.Update(Entity);

    serviceResult.Success = result.Successfull;
    serviceResult.ResultTitle = (result.Successfull ? Error.GetErrorMessage(Error.CorrectTransaction) : Error.GetErrorMessage(Error.InternalServerError));
    //serviceResult.Messages.Add(result.Successfull ? "Updated" : "Failed");
    serviceResult.ResultObject = MapperHelper.
    Instance.Map<Ent, Vm>(result.Data);

    this.Repository.SaveChanges();
    return serviceResult;
}
```

This is my update user controller

```
[HttpPost("users/edit/{id}")]
public ActionResult UserEdit(UserViewModel userViewModel)
{
    var users = userService.Update(userViewModel).ResultObject;

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
}
```

The repository and service are doing their jobs looking for an user by an id and updating their values but when the UserEdit Controller it's done my changes are not being saved in the database.

Can anyone give me some advice to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Why in title is onion architecture, when this is simple CRUD?

Comment: @AdamWyżgoł just wanted to be more specific

Comment: The tracked entity is ToUpdate but you are trying to update the mapped viewmodel object. Update the properties of ToUpdate with the properties in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EF relies on internal entity change tracking to determine what operations it needs to perform in the database. All your `Update` method does is call `SaveChanges`, so simply changes being made to the entity are not being tracked for some reason, and when you call `SaveChanges`, EF sees no work it needs to do, and just returns. As to why your entity changes aren't being tracked, there's not enough of your repository here to tell.

However, I will say that this is one of the paramount reasons to *not* use the repository pattern with EF. It's far too easy to do stuff that borks EF's change tracking, and 99 times out of 100, that's exactly what developers do. When you use an ORM like EF, *that* is your data layer. It implements the repository and unit of work patterns already. Not every "layer" in your architecture has to actually be owned by you, and this is a critical mistake far too many developers make. Just use your context directly. That's what it's for.

Now, purists might argue that you'll have a hard dependency on EF. Well, guess what? You do regardless. You've chosen it as an ORM, and that decision doesn't and shouldn't come lightly. What if you want to switch it out with something else down the line? That question always gets raised as well. Simply, you won't. The friction involved in switching out something like an ORM is such that it will *never* be a business priority.

Nevertheless, if you want to truly abstract the dependency, you should be looking at patterns like CQRS or microservices, which unlike a redundant and useless repository layer, actually do add value to your application. However, those patterns are complex to implement and overkill for most applications.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but using a repository pattern will put some distance between your controller and EF, so your entire app is not dependent on EF, only your data layer/repositories are.

Comment: Incorrect. The repository pattern is for low-level data access, such as actual SQL query strings. Wrapping EF in a repository doesn't magically make the dependency go away. You're still using LINQ to Entities and such in your code, and if you're using DI, and you should be, you still need to inject the context in your repo, so the app still knows about it. Regardless, you'll still have a reference to EF in your app, and there's no way around that.

Comment: In other words, it doesn't accomplish any of the supposed goals people use it for, and it's also redundant and just more code you need to maintain and test.

Comment: The repository pattern separates the data context from the controller. Dependencies never magically go away, you just move them into a position that enables you replace them with as little hassle as possible. Using EF directly from a controller will mean you have to rewrite the entire thing if you ever decide to drop EF.

Comment: On the other hand, make damn sure you are using the right tools for data access up front so you won't have to strip them out later.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, the friction of switching ORMs is such that it will virtually never be a business priority. Apps, especially web apps, have a definite shelf-life anyways, so it's far more likely, you'll rebuild from the ground up before you ever switch out an ORM. That aside, there's actual appropriate patterns to use for this kind of abstraction, such as service layer, CQRS, and microservices. The repository pattern is the wrong approach no matter how you slice it.